# how to for each the data that return by python3.5 from mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I use `python3.5` and connect `mysql` to get the data. and I don't know how to get the data of each column without the way of **creating a Model.**

```
# encoding=utf-8
import mysql.connector

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 3306
USER_NAME = "root"
PASSWORD = "anywhere"
DB_NAME = "test"


def create_db_connection():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=USER_NAME, password=PASSWORD, database=DB_NAME)
        return conn
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(e))


def find_all_user():
    sql = "select * from test_users"
    conn = create_db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        return cursor.fetchall()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("failed to find user by sql ={}, cause : {}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))


def main():
    user_list = find_all_user()
    print(user_list)
    for user in user_list:
        # how to get the data of user such as id, name ...
        print(user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**table test_users**

```
create table test_users(
  id primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(128) default null,
  -- and other columns ...
);
```

In the main method, how could I get the data of the **column id, name**
and I tried to use `user[0]`, this way could get the `id`, `user[1]` could get `name`, but you cannot know which index if you don't know the table.

so is any other way to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for user in user_list:
        print(user["id"], user["name"])
```

Comment: not work, `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`  .

Comment: @BenD please print user and give it me:)

Comment: `user = [(1, 'userName')]` sorry, too busy to give you the ans. there is the user-print. I still could not print as what I want .%>_<%

Comment: @BenD realy this is USER(or user_list)? if is user you could: `print(user[0][0],user[0][1])`  or if it is user list you could `print(user[0],user[1])`

Comment: it is user, and user_list is: `[(1,'userName1'),(2,'userName2')]`.

Comment: @BenD if `[(1,'userName1'),(2,'userName2')]` then `(1,'userName1')` and `(2,'userName2')` are user in each iteration. so you can use: `print(user[0],user[1])`

Comment: but I want to get data of user's ID and name, how could I know the the index of `id` or `name` by `user[index]`?

Comment: @BenD what are data of user's id and name? where are that? if saved in other table on database you need Foreign key of user in that table

Comment: ```create table test_users(
  id primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(128) default null,
  -- and other columns ...
);```   see my question, this is the table.

Comment: @BenD i saw that. your question is confusing. `user[0],user[1],...user[-1]` are data of each user.